# Is this considered actual Graphic Design or part of photography?

Tags: photo-editing, design-principles, designers, photography, graphic-styles

Kindly have a look at this. I'm not sharing the link of Instagram page because it might violate policies.

[image]

I've designed all of them. Most of them (where box, pills and sachets are present) are photo manipulations. That is, the product image and photo were separate things, merged together to look like a product photo shoot.

Apart from that, there are some GIFs and human photos with some text over them.

I do similar work (photo manipulation) for Facebook ads also. But those have little minimal look and text copies over design, so it looks like an ad.

Now, I'm enjoying this stuff, but I have a **fear** that I might stay behind other Graphic Designers. **Sometimes I feel I'm doing the photography work, not Graphic Design.**

Because, many times I assume that *actual* Graphic Design is illustrations done with colors and paths (like we do in Illustrator), logo designs and designs that contain colors and texts (not real photos). I'm possibly wrong while thinking this, but I don't have any reason for that.

So is this actually photography work or considered Graphic Design?

Comment: Are you **taking** any of the photos are are they all merely stock images? The thing is 90% of the work is in the photos. One would need to see the original and what you may have altered to make a judgement as to whether it's merely photo manipulation or design/layout..

Comment: Actual graphic design is problem solving and communications: did you solve your clients problems with photos? Did you communicate your client ideas with photos? If yes, I don't see a problem

Comment: @Scott I don't take photographs. Stock images. Also I didn't get the second sentence. Please elaborate?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I guess it is Graphic Design but the designs can be good and bad?

Comment: what is graphic design? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_design

Comment: Sure, but your question doesn't seem to be about good or bad design (which is subjective and once again can be only measured by answering a question: did the design solve a prolem or not?). Illustrations done with colors and paths could be a bad design. Two letters put together in a specific way could be a good design.

Comment: Well, if they are merely stock images it would be more along the lines of layout but it's a [fine line](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58257/what-is-the-difference-between-layout-and-design). My **opinion** is that a *designer* creates. A *layout artist* arranges.  If you are doing considerable photo manipulation that may be a factor, but no one here can tell how *much* any of the stock photos have been altered. Face it, your cousin could buy a stock photo and then throw some text on it. Heck, my mom could. That wouldn't make them designers specifically.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I mean if it were communicating and somehow promoting the product, it would be called grapahic design?

Comment: @Scott some of the manipulations I do are very easy to do. But some (not shared here. Will be posted on Instagram in future) requires 2-3 hours to fix lights/angles/shadows and masking etc. I don't think everyone could do that.

Comment: Agreed Vikas, and I'm **not** discounting such work. I merely think it's subjective as to whether photo manipulation is graphic design.. again with stock photos 90% of the work is done by the photographer (framing, lighting, etc) in most instances. it may merely be photo manipulation. Which is a skill in itself that *many* designers don't possess.

Comment: @Scott okay. But please see the Instagram photos has different kinds of posts. We are talking about merely photo manipulation. I wanted an overall opinion considering all of them, because I fear I'm not doing Graphic Design and doing something different, which in future can be *bad* while searching for a new Graphic Design job.

Comment: Of course. In my opinion. Once again, all this is very subjective. There are people who say that digital art isn't art because it's made with a computer or people who say that contemporary art isn't art because it doesn't depict the life we see. It's all a matter of perception of you and people around you.

Comment: It is all **very** subjective. And I think a great deal can't be narrowed down to a small collection of samples. Most designers work on myriad projects all ranging different skill sets. Some projects may not be "design" as much as "layout" or "photo manipulation" or "drawing" -- but it's the *combination of all these skills* that can qualify one as a Graphic Designer.

Comment: @Scott got it. Let's make it less subjective. Kindly have a look on it: https://www.instagram.com/careof/ Our brand also have similar products. So my/our ultimate aim is make content *like* these. They have lots of varieties in their posts. This includes photography, and other stuff. But in our case, photography is replaced by photo manipulation. Do you think this is Graphic Design? Or still same answer?

Comment: Same answer it would depend upon **how much** manipulation there was, the nature of the manipulation, and the overall final piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will look more psychological analysis than a graphic design one.

> I've designed all of them

You answered yourself. It is design, not photography.

> I have a fear that I might stay behind other Graphic Designers.

Everyone on the planet will stay behind another colleague in some respect, so, no big deal here.

> many times I assume that actual Graphic Design is illustrations

Nope, Illustrations are illustrations... made by Illustrators, so, if you are doing illustrations you are an illustrator... (I am very profound thinker)

> done with colors and paths (like we do in Illustrator),

That is a specific tool for a specific type of illustration, vector illustration, but you can use a painting program, (which will make you probably a digital painter n_n) or you can use physical medium, like paper, ink, paint, pastels, chocolate muse, or icecream if you want.

But also you could do achromatic work ;o)

> I'm doing the photography work

Are you using that device called the camera? That is the tool a photographer uses.

Are you controlling the exposure, illumination, changing lenses, rearranging the subject, and then "click"?

> logo designs

That is a very specific branch. Logo design.

> contain colors and texts

I talked about color, but text... this is a good one. Design without any text? probably still in the realm of illustration.

One technique of illustration is a "collage".

> So is this actual photography work or considered Graphic Design?

I already answered this. No camera no photographer.

> I'm possibly wrong while thinking this, but I don't have any reason for that.

You are actually wrong thinking this... because the whole point is this:

> Now, I'm enjoying this stuff.

So, forget about branding. Yes, some definitions are interesting, yes sometimes we do things that are out of the scope.

This case is insignificant next to the power of... web design? where you are sometimes coding?

Unless you have some kind of "union labor contract" where your activities are super defined, all that is into the scope of a graphic designer. Photography? Yes, Illustration? yes, coding? sometimes, lettering, calligraphy? If you are talented enough. Branding, some marketing, some printing technical skill, some fixing computers also".

But in the end... who cares? just:

> Now, I'm enjoying this stuff.

---

**Are you a graphic designer?**

Here is the question. Are you solving visual communication problems to be sent to a public? then probably yes.

Comment: Thanks for answering *each* doubt. What is *So, forget about branding*?

Comment: Also, is some communication (consider average of all posts) involved in my designs I've shared?

Answer (score 1):

You have put together compositions which have photos, a little text and maybe some drawings, too. The results can be said to be graphic designs as soon as they are not random, but try to present something or lift something up - something that you want to tell or your customer wants to tell. They are not designs if there's no purpose. A purpose can be to show that you were able to do these. The photos seem to have high technical quality although they are blurry in your screenshot. The ability to shoot high quality photos is well worth a design but in this case the design for it is generated automatically by Instagram.

Do the watchers get impressed and do you have something more to say than "hey, I have composed this" is different thing.

Comment: *The ability to shoot high quality photos is well worth a design but in this case the* *design for it is generated automatically by Instagram*. Can you please explain in easy sentence.

Comment: There are plenty of photos which I only believe to be sharp. I see they have good contrast and white balance and each of them seem to have a subject. So I believe they are high quality photos. Instagram's terms state that you must have a right to use the photos and you have not credited anybody so I believe the images are shot by you. Instagram has tiled them with certain spacings and sizes to straight rows and columns - quite trivial layout, I say, but it's made by Instagram.

Comment: Oops. Do you understand I didn't mean to get answers about the current Instagram layout? I know it's Instagram's layout. But I just shared it because sharing multiple photos was a bad idea. I wanted answer about overall posts, not the grid.

Comment: I understand it. But the image gallery shows a bunch of compositions which contain good base photos, so the gallery is as Instagram's job presenting you have an ability to shoot good photos. The individual compositions are your designs if you try to tell something with them. If you have some random method to select and place small things onto a big base image, they are not designs. I do not claim anything of 1) the quality of your design and 2) do there exist designs

Answer (score 1):

I think this type of work generally falls under the broad field of 'graphic design', but I would also add it kind of touches on the lower end spectrum of the field.

I mean, you are clearly solving some problems there, creating compositions that communicate ideas, but this social media work has a very short life span and is generally paid in bulk by clients, with no long-term added value. True graphic design involves some more in-depth thinking, solving more elaborate tasks that help clients on the long run (branding, packaging, editorial).

Social media type 'graphic design' —  as in, 'let`s stick these 3 words next to a stock photo somehow' —  is often listed under day-to-day marketing services for most clients, and just creating stuff for Instagram will keep your work limited.

Then, when you want to move up to a true design job, you'll have trouble applying with just social media work.